# Having trouble transferring FluidSurvey Data

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I'll try to keep this short and simple. I'm in a bit of a pickle here in regards to some new functionality my client wants. He runs a survey company and has integrated FluidSurveys into his website via specific address.

He hosts many surveys here with no issue, however one of his clients insists that their data be compiled and pushed to another server using zapier using the FluidSurveys to mySQL "zap".

Upon entering the information in zapier and getting everything ready to go, I get this error

```
(OperationalError) (1130, "Host 'ec2-54-86-9-50.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server") None None
```

All i need to know is if there is a common way to fix the permissions to make this connection possible.